# Node.js - React.js web app unable to render view with params in URL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, redux

I was doing a Node - React course in [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/server-side-nodejs/home/welcome), the course is really outdated so i decided to follow the course but update the code to current versions of frameworks and technologies. The project was to build up a restaurant web app, all the app is working well but the part showing the menu is supposed to render a specific dish when clicked, but when done, the app crashes showing the following error.[image: Console error] The code of the route in the server is:
**dishRouter.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const cors = require('./cors');
const authenticate = require('../authenticate');
const Dishes = require('../models/dishes');


.
.
.

dishRouter.route('/:dishId')
.options(
  cors.corsWithOptions, 
  (req, res) => { 
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
)
.get(
  cors.cors,
  (req, res, next) => {
    Dishes.findById(req.params.dishId)
    .populate('comments.author')
    .then((dish) => {
      console.log('Dish Created ', dish);
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json(dish);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
  }
)
.post(
  cors.corsWithOptions,
  authenticate.verifyUser,
  authenticate.verifyAdmin,  
  (req, res, _next) => {
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.end(`POST operation not supported on /dishes/${req.params.dishId}`);
  }
)
.put(
  cors.corsWithOptions,
  authenticate.verifyUser,
  authenticate.verifyAdmin,
  (req, res, next) => {
    Dishes.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.dishId, {
      $set: req.body
    }, { new: true })
    .then((dish) => {
      console.log('Dish Created ', dish);
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json(dish);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
  }
)
.delete(
  cors.corsWithOptions,
  authenticate.verifyUser,
  authenticate.verifyAdmin,
  (req, res, next) => {
    Dishes.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.dishId)
    .then((resp) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json(resp);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
  }
);

module.exports = dishRouter;
```

the router `dishRouter.route('/:dishId')` is the responsible to handle the specific dish information

The client side code
**mainComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import Contact from './ContactComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import Favorites from './FavoriteComponent';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import About from './AboutComponent'
import {Routes, Route, Navigate, useParams, useNavigate, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'; //Switch changed to routes Also redirect is changed to Navigate since version 6
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { postComment, postFeedback,fetchDishes, fetchComments, fetchPromos, fetchLeaders,loginUser, logoutUser, fetchFavorites, postFavorite, deleteFavorite  } from '../redux/ActionCreators';
import { actions } from 'react-redux-form';
import {TransitionGroup, CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';

// --------Hook to use withRouter from v5 in actual v6
export const withRouter = (Component) => {
  const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const history = useNavigate();
    
    return (
      <Component
        history={history}
        {...props}
        />
    );
  };
  
  return Wrapper;
};
//------------End of Hook

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        dishes: state.dishes,
        comments: state.comments,
        promotions: state.promotions,
        leaders: state.leaders,
        favorites: state.favorites,
        auth: state.auth
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  postComment: (dishId, rating, author, comment) => dispatch(postComment(dishId, rating, author, comment)),
  postFeedback: (firstName, lastName, telnum, email, agree, contactType, message) => dispatch(postFeedback(firstName, lastName, telnum, email, agree, contactType, message)),
  fetchDishes: () => { dispatch(fetchDishes())},
  fetchComments: () => dispatch(fetchComments()),
  fetchPromos: () => dispatch(fetchPromos()),
  fetchLeaders: () => dispatch(fetchLeaders()),

  resetFeedbackForm: () => { dispatch(actions.reset('feedback'))},
  loginUser: (creds) => dispatch(loginUser(creds)),
  logoutUser: () => dispatch(logoutUser()),
  fetchFavorites: () => dispatch(fetchFavorites()),
  postFavorite: (dishId) => dispatch(postFavorite(dishId)),
  deleteFavorite: (dishId) => dispatch(deleteFavorite(dishId))
});


class Main extends Component {

  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchDishes();
    this.props.fetchComments();
    this.props.fetchPromos();
    this.props.fetchLeaders();
    this.props.fetchFavorites();
  }
  render(){

    const HomePage = () => {
      // console.log(this.props)
      return(
          <Home 
              dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.featured)[0]}
              dishesLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
              dishesErrMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}

              promotion={this.props.promotions.promotions.filter((promo) => promo.featured)[0]}
              promoLoading={this.props.promotions.isLoading}
              promoErrMess={this.props.promotions.errMess}
              
              leader={this.props.leaders.leaders.filter((leader) => leader.featured)[0]}
              leaderLoading={this.props.leaders.isLoading}
              leaderErrMess={this.props.leaders.errMess}
          />
      );
    }

    const DishWithId = () => {
      let params = useParams();
      return(
        this.props.auth.isAuthenticated
        ?
          <DishDetail dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish._id === parseInt(params.dishId,10))[0]}
            isLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
            errMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
            comments={this.props.comments.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(params.dishId,10))}
            commentsErrMess={this.props.comments.errMess}
            postComment={this.props.postComment}
            favorite={this.props.favorites.favorites.dishes.some((dish) => dish._id === params.dishId)}
            postFavorite={this.props.postFavorite}
          />
          :
          <DishDetail dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish._id === parseInt(params.dishId,10))[0]}
          isLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
          errMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
          comments={this.props.comments.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(params.dishId,10))}
          commentsErrMess={this.props.comments.errMess}
          postComment={this.props.postComment}
          favorite={false}
          postFavorite={this.props.postFavorite}
        />
      );
    };
    


    const AnimatedSwitch = () => {
      const location = useLocation();
      console.log("location", location);
      console.log("Props", this.props);
      return (
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition key ={location.key} classNames='page' timeout = {300}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage/>}/> {/*Also component must be changed to element since i am using V6*/}
              <Route exact path="/menu" element= {<Menu dishes={this.props.dishes} />} />  {/* in previous version this must look as: () => element= {<Menu dishes={this.props.dishes} />} */}
              <Route path = "/menu/:dishId" element={<DishWithId />} />
              {/* <PrivateRoute exact path="/favorites" component={() => <Favorites favorites={this.props.favorites} deleteFavorite={this.props.deleteFavorite} />} /> */}
              <Route exact path ='/contactus' element={<Contact postFeedback={this.props.postFeedback} resetFeedbackForm={this.props.resetFeedbackForm}/>} />
              <Route path = '/aboutus' element={<About leaders = {this.props.leaders}/>} />
              <Route path="*"element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
              {/* Instead of redirect the above snippet is needed to redirect if there is no matched url */}
            </Routes>
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
      );
    };

    
  return (
    
    <div>
      <Header
        auth={this.props.auth} 
        loginUser={this.props.loginUser} 
        logoutUser={this.props.logoutUser} />
      <AnimatedSwitch/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

**menuComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay,CardTitle,Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem} from 'reactstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';
import {baseUrl} from '../shared/baseUrl';
function RenderMenuItem ({dish, onClick}) {
      return (
          <Card>
              <Link to={ `/menu/${dish._id}` } >
                  <CardImg width="100%" src={baseUrl + dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                      <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
              </Link>
          </Card>
      );
  }
    const Menu = (props) =>{
      const menu = props.dishes.dishes.map((dish) => { // antes era this.props.dishes pero ahora props pasa como parametro a la funcion por lo cual this no es necesario
        return (
          <div key={dish._id} id = 'dishes' className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
            <RenderMenuItem dish={dish}/>
          </div>
        );
    });
    if (props.dishes.isLoading){
      return(
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <Loading />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else if(props.dishes.errMess){
      return(
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <h4>{props.dishes.errMess}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else
      return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <Breadcrumb>
                    <BreadcrumbItem><Link to="/home">Home</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
                    <BreadcrumbItem active>Menu</BreadcrumbItem>
                </Breadcrumb>
                <div className="col-12">
                    <h3>Menu</h3>
                    <hr />
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                {menu}
            </div>
        </div>
      );
  }


export default Menu;
```

**dishdetailComponent.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg,CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle,
         Breadcrumb,BreadcrumbItem, Button,
        Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody,
         Label, Col, Row} from 'reactstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Control, LocalForm, Errors } from 'react-redux-form';
import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';
import {FadeTransform, Fade, Stagger} from 'react-animation-components';

/**........................ comment component ends ................................................. */
//// validators
const required = (val) => val && val.length; //value > 0
const maxLength = (len) => (val) => !(val) || (val.length <= len);
const minLength = (len) => (val) => (val) && (val.length >= len);

class CommentForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            isCommentFormModalOpen: false
        };

        this.toggleCommentFormModal = this.toggleCommentFormModal.bind(this);
        this.handleCommentFormSubmit = this.handleCommentFormSubmit.bind(this);

    }

    handleCommentFormSubmit(values) {
        
        this.props.postComment(this.props.dishId, values.rating, values.author, values.comment);


    }

    toggleCommentFormModal() {
        this.setState({
            isCommentFormModalOpen: !this.state.isCommentFormModalOpen
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Button outline onClick={this.toggleCommentFormModal}>
                    <span className="fa fa-comments fa-lg"></span> Submit Comment
                </Button>


                {/* commentform  Modal */}
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.isCommentFormModalOpen} toggle={this.toggleCommentFormModal} >
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleCommentFormModal}> Submit Comment </ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>

                        <LocalForm onSubmit={(values) => this.handleCommentFormSubmit(values)}>

                            {/* rating */}
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Label htmlFor="rating" md={12} >Rating</Label>
                                <Col md={12}>
                                    <Control.select model=".rating"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        name="rating"
                                        id="rating"
                                        validators={{
                                            required
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <option>Please Select</option>
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>4</option>
                                        <option>5</option>
                                    </Control.select>
                                    <Errors
                                        className="text-danger"
                                        model=".author"
                                        show="touched"
                                        messages={{
                                            required: 'Required',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </Col>
                            </Row>


                            {/* author */}
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Label htmlFor="author" md={12}> Your Name </Label>
                                <Col md={12}>
                                    <Control.text model=".author" id="author" name="author"
                                        placeholder="First Name"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        validators={{
                                            required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(15)
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Errors
                                        className="text-danger"
                                        model=".author"
                                        show="touched"
                                        messages={{
                                            required: 'Required',
                                            minLength: 'Must be greater than 2 characters',
                                            maxLength: 'Must be 15 characters or less'
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </Col>
                            </Row>




                            {/* comment */}
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Label htmlFor="comment" md={12}>Comment</Label>
                                <Col md={12}>
                                    <Control.textarea model=".comment" id="comment" name="comment"
                                        rows="6"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        validators={{
                                            required
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Errors
                                        className="text-danger"
                                        model=".author"
                                        show="touched"
                                        messages={{
                                            required: 'Required',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </Col>

                            </Row>

                            {/* submit button */}
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Col>
                                    <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                                        Submit
                                    </Button>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>

                        </LocalForm>

                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>


            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

/**........................ comment component ends ................................................. */


function RenderDish({dish,favorite, postFavorite}){
        
  if (dish != null){
    return(
      <div className='col-12 col-md-5 m-1'>
        <FadeTransform in 
            transformProps={{
                exitTransform: 'scale(0.5) translateY(-50%)'
            }}>
        <Card>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={baseUrl + dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>       
            <CardImgOverlay>
                <Button outline color="primary" onClick={() => favorite ? console.log('Already favorite') : postFavorite(dish._id)}>
                    {favorite ?
                        <span className="fa fa-heart"></span>
                        : 
                        <span className="fa fa-heart-o"></span>
                    }
                </Button>
            </CardImgOverlay>
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
        </FadeTransform>
      </div>
    );
  }
  else{
    return(
      <div></div>
      );
        }
}

    
function RenderComments({comments,postComment,dishId}){
  if(comments != null){
      const review = comments.map((comment) =>{
        return (
            <Stagger in >
            <div key = {comment._id} className='container'>
                <Fade in>
                    <li id='comments'>
                        <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                        <p>--{comment.author.firstname} {comment.author.lastname} , {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',{year: 'numeric', month:'short', day:'2-digit'}).format(new Date(Date.parse(comment.date)))}</p>
                    </li>
                </Fade>
            </div>
            </Stagger>
            
        );
      });
        return(
           
            <div className='col-12 col-md-5 m-1'>
                {review}
                <CommentForm dishId={dishId} postComment={postComment} />     
            </div>
            
        )
  }
        
}

const DishDetail = (props)=> {
  
    if (props.isLoading){
      return(
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <Loading />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else if(props.errMess){
      return(
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <h4>{props.errMess}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else if (props.dish != null){
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
              <Breadcrumb>
                  <BreadcrumbItem><Link to="/menu">Menu</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
                  <BreadcrumbItem active>{props.dish.name}</BreadcrumbItem>
              </Breadcrumb>
              <div className="col-12">
                  <h3>{props.dish.name}</h3>
                  <hr />
              </div>                
          </div>
          <div className="row">
              
                  <RenderDish dish={props.dish} favorite={props.favorite} postFavorite={props.postFavorite}/>
                  <RenderComments comments={props.comments}
                                  postComment={props.postComment}
                                  dishId={props.dish._id} />
                              
          </div>

        </div>
      );
    }
    else{
        return(
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}


export default DishDetail;
```

Also the favorites is a feature to add favorites dishes to a user.

from client side.:
**favoriteComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Media, Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';
import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';

function RenderMenuItem({ dish, deleteFavorite }) {
    return(
        <Media tag="li">
            <Media left middle>
                <Media object src={baseUrl + dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            </Media>
            <Media body className="ml-5">
                <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
                <p>{dish.description}</p>
                <Button outline color="danger" onClick={() => deleteFavorite(dish._id)}>
                    <span className="fa fa-times"></span>
                </Button>
            </Media>
        </Media>
    );
}

const Favorites = (props) => {

    if (props.favorites.isLoading) {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <Loading />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    else if (props.favorites.errMess) {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <h4>{props.favorites.errMess}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    else if (props.favorites.favorites) {

        const favorites = props.favorites.favorites.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                <div key={dish._id} className="col-12 mt-5">
                    <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} deleteFavorite={props.deleteFavorite} />
                </div>
            );
        });

        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <Breadcrumb>
                        <BreadcrumbItem><Link to='/home'>Home</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
                        <BreadcrumbItem active>My Favorites</BreadcrumbItem>
                    </Breadcrumb>
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <h3>My Favorites</h3>
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <Media list>
                        {favorites}
                    </Media>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    else {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <h4>You have no favorites</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Favorites;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious
**cannot access property "dishes", this.props.favorites.favorites is null**
for some reason the favorites object is null and you cannot access the property dishes of the null object

```
favorite={this.props.favorites.favorites?.dishes?.some((dish) => dish._id === params.dishId)}
```